# Perform VLOOKUP queries based on the Day of the Month

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to come up with a formula to get the values populated through VLOOKUP command based on the Day of the Month.

For example:

If it is a first of the month , I want to return the value for Type W (Column A) as 1 and for the other days , I want to return the value 5.

[image]

I am trying to get these values through VLOOKUP command in another sheet which looks like below:

[image]

Appreciate all your help !!

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the 3rd argument of VLOOKUP dynamic based on `DAY(TODAY())`, e.g.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$5,IF(DAY(TODAY())=1,2,3),FALSE)
```